Assistance Needed: UnrecognizedClientException when Calling StopTask in ECS Cluster
I am facing an issue while trying to stop a specific task in an ECS cluster on AWS using the chaosaws action.
Error Description:
An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the StopTask operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:
I have tried running aws configure multiple times to ensure that the correct credentials are set.
Verified the AWS credentials and made sure they have the required permissions for ECS operations.
Questions:
Has anyone encountered the UnrecognizedClientException error when trying to stop a task in ECS?
Could this be an access issue or something related to the AWS credentials?
Are there any additional configurations or permissions that need to be set for the stop_task operation?

Are you doing this through the AWS CLI tool or something? Have you tried making any other AWS calls with those credentials? Please provide enough information in your question to explain how you reproduce the problem. That error usually means you have invalid credentials configured, or your computer's system clock is not set correctly.
